# Is it necessary to test the integrity of an archive if it returns "Everything is okay" when running 7zip via the command line?

Tags: windows, 7-zip

Each time I compress a file via the command line 7zip is nice enough to return "Everything is okay". I know that I can test the integrity of an archive if I run the command `7z t archive.zip` but is it necessary if the former is being displayed? What added advantage is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Necessary" is a somewhat relative term. When 7-Zip says that everything is okay, this just means that it didn't detect any errors during its compression process, and that it thinks it wrote out the compressed file successfully.

It's conceivable that 7-Zip could have a bug that would cause it to fail to detect an error in compression. This is probably fairly unlikely, since 7-Zip is widely used and therefore pretty well-tested in practice. A more likely scenario is a hardware problem that causes 7-Zip not to produce or write out a correct output. This could be due to a problem with your hard disk, your RAM, overheating of hardware, or any number of other things. 7-Zip is not likely to detect such an error. So doing a test of the archive afterwards is a decent way to detect such problems, but not totally guaranteed either. (I'd say it's not at all unlikely that you might run into bad hardware at some point in your lifetime.)

So, the bottom line is, I'd say that if the data's important to you, then go ahead and test the archive afterwards.

Comment: I'd go further: if the data in the archive is *really* important, verifying the archive integrity isn't enough.  Unzip it (on a different machine if possible) and then compare the unzipped contents to the originals (using, e.g., windiff).

Comment: @HarryJohnston -- Quite correct.  And of course, you also need to have some strategy (such as actually running the archived app/whatever on the other system) to assure that you didn't miss any files.  Many a system backup has been found unusable because of omitted files.

Comment: @Harry Johnston - How would you automate the process of comparing files?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey - 1) Before compression, do an md5sum on all files you want to save. 2) Compress  3) Copy to new system 4) Decompress 5) Compare md5sums with what you had on source system

Comment: @Nifle - That's what I am planning to do but that isn't comparing content as Harry mentioned. The assumption is that the files are ASCII and can be compared.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: by "compare" I mean "check that the contents are identical" so the files don't need to be ASCII and Nifle's suggestion is sound.  Personally I'd use SHA512 rather than MD5, but that's more a matter of taste than an objective preference.  If you can network between the two machines (or if you do it on a single machine) another option is to directly compare the binary content using any suitable tool.  I usually use windiff (from the Windows resource kit) but it's not a great option as it sometimes has trouble with large directories.

Comment: If you really want to do a direct comparison, I'd install Cygwin and use `diff -r`, though there's a learning curve involved if you're not familiar with Unix-like systems. The checksum approach is really best overall. MD5 will do nicely here; the benefit you get from SHA-512 is totally negligible for this particular use case, and it will take substantially longer for large files.

Comment: @Harry Johnston - Thanks. Seeing that the files are substantially large, like to use a method of comparing files however not burdening the system.

Comment: @jjlin: my experience is that SHA-512 is just as fast as MD5 in practice, because the bottleneck isn't the CPU but the process of reading the file from disk.  However, I think you're right that it doesn't give any better protection in this case.